# SelectItem is not working in smartgwt 2.5

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, smartgwt

My SelectItem box is not displaying combo box items when i click on down arrow.

My code is :

DynamicForm dynamicForm=new DynamicForm();

```
    VLayout layout=new VLayout();

    SelectItem selectItem=new SelectItem("name", "title");

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> valueMap=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    valueMap.put("Value 1", "Item 1");
    valueMap.put("Value 2", "Item 2");
    valueMap.put("Value 3", "Item 3");

    selectItem.setValueMap(valueMap);

    dynamicForm.setFields(selectItem);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(dynamicForm);
```

Please help me.

Comment: I would look for some external CSS being loading. They can sometimes mess up with the SmartGWT CSS

Answer (score 1):

I test your code as it is and it works, no reason it wouldn't.
Sorry I use 2.4 . So check if you have this version too